# How can I count number of students in a class using Mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have two tables:

---

```
Student table

studentID         fullname        gender         DOB            classID
91110010003          A             M          03/03/1993       25CCHT02
91110010004          B             M          08/03/1993       25CCHT02
91110010005          C             M          04/14/1991       25CCHT02
93510010005          D             M          07/27/1993       25CCDH02
93510010008          E             F          03/10/1993       25CCDH02
93510010009          F             M          06/09/1990       25CCDH02
93510010010          G             M          18/12/1989       25CCDH02
99510170307          H             M          05/06/1991       25CCDH02
99510180112          L             M          07/12/1992       25CCDH02
99510180150          M             M          22/03/1993       25CCDH02
```

---

```
LOP 
class ID                 class name 
25CCDH02                 3D design
25CCHT02                    QTM 
25CCLM01                    LT
```

---

I want to create a statement which show the result like :

```
class ID                 class name              student_count 
25CCDH02                 3D design                     7
25CCHT02                    QTM                        3
25CCLM01                    LT                         0
```

Answer (score 0):

Group by the columns you want to be unique and then use COUNT() to get the count of each group

```
select l.`class id`, l.`class name`, count(s.studentID) s_count
from lop l
left join student s on s.classID = l.`class id`
group by l.`class id`, l.`class name`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can left join the student table with LOP table and then find the required aggregates:

```
select l.classid,
    l.classname,
    count(*) as student_count
from lop l
left join student s on l.classid = s.classid
group by l.classid,
    l.classname;
```